# Difference between Omniture h23 and h26 code

Tags: adobe-analytics

I am upgrading my Web Analytics Omniture reporting from h23 to h26 code base.

I have two questions:
1) What is the difference between Omniture h23 and h26?
2) I see that a new variable "fid" is firing when I upgraded to h26? What is that variable and what is it's purpose?

Please guide.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you'd be better off simply reading the release notes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Release Notes are the place to go for this information
https://microsite.omniture.com/t2/help/en_US/sc/appmeasurement/release/index.html#JavaScript_H_code_Legacy

C.